# installation issues using flash drive

Tags: system-installation, usb, hard-drive

Ubuntu doesn't allow me to fully install it because at the end when it asks, "Ubuntu needs to restart. Would you like to do it now?", without hesitation I click continue. Upon rebooting it prompts me a 2nd time if I want to install or try it out.

If I remove the flash drive after rebooting, I get a message saying the computer has no OS.

Comment: There was a problem with your boot loader installation or more likely your BIOS isn't selecting the correct device. Try pressing F8 / F12 / F10 (depending on your computer) and manually select the hard drive you installed Ubuntu to. If that works, go into your BIOS and change your boot order. If that doesn't work - which device did you choose to install the bootloader to? It was a drop down box when you selected your hard drive / partition to install to.

Comment: i downloaded ubuntu on a flashdrive put it in ran ubuntu deleted windows and now the usb is acting as a cd so the computer needs the flashdrive to have ubuntu and now thats my only os

Comment: i know what i did but dont know how to fix it i downloaded my grub on my flash and i dont know how to force that to move to my harddrive

Comment: Is this a UEFI machine?  Did you try to "boot first hard disk" option on the USB?

Answer (score 1):

Boot the USB flash again, use "Try Ubuntu", press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to go to a terminal and type:

```
sudo parted --list
sudo grub-install /dev/XdY
```

Where `X` and `Y` are in the output of the first command after `Disk /dev/` (probably `s` and `a`)

Then shut down the machine completely, remove the USB disk and start again!

Comment: it tells me permission denied

Comment: ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ /dev/sda2
bash: /dev/sda2: Permission denied

Comment: sda2 is my hdd im running it on sda which is my flash

Comment: `sda` is a disk and `sda2` is a partition.  Please edit your question and provide the output to `sudo parted --list`, in "Try Ubuntu" mode, please?  That way I will be able to provide an exact command you need to run.

Comment: As you're a reputation 1 user: If this answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of this text, which means [Yes, this answer is valid](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)!  **;-)**